# problem with compiling 64 bt dll on a 32 bit windows via TDM-GCC

Tags: windows, gcc, dll, 32bit-64bit, tdm-mingw

I use 32 bit windows and my assistant has 64 bit. We both use gcc (I specifically use tdm-gcc. My assistant uses qt which also uses gcc as far as I'm aware). I wanted to write a very simple plugin in a form of simple `.dll` for my assistant to use from inside of her application. To do so I need just to compile my `.dll` for windows 32 (like 32 bit XP) as a `.dll` for a windows 64 (like win 7 or 10).

I found that `-m64` option could work. However when I compile it and she links it and tries to call my functions it shows that this application with this plugin `.dll` I've made (on 32 bit windows with tdm-gcc with that `-m64` option) silently crashes (program ends and no output is generated).

What is the problem with that? The test we were doing was simple like exporting a function that just returns `232323` and trying to receive and print it on application side - but is still doesn't work.My guess is that this 64 bit `.dll` is wrong (dependency walker shows dependency on kernel32, isn't it 32 bit specific?)

Should I do something more than putting `-m64` to make my plugin compile to 64 bit and work properly there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showed it most probably work.. She cant link it in QT from unknown reasons to me (we work remotely and i cannot check) but she succesfully linked it dynamically so it seems -m64 in fact suffice

Comment: Did you produce separate import libraries for the two architectures?  Just because the list of exported functions is the same doesn't make the import library interchangeable.  Or are you not using import libraries at all and trusting the gcc linker to analyze the DLL exports?

Comment: Ben Voigt - i didnt generated import libs, gcc generally dont need that -llibname and he just links..... this is a problem of my girl assistant and QT i dont know what it was.... i only was in confusion if that -m64 should work at all , it now showed it work when dynamically linked.. so my doubts are answered